# Can a DataGridView cell be instructed to mask entered characters with an asterisk?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewtextboxcell

Is there a way to replace the characters entered in a cell of a `DataGridView` with an asterisk while entering them? If so, how can I do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As Mark Rideout writes in [his answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/2881d336-7f9e-43d6-a262-813a540f992c/) found on social.msdn.microsoft.com

> Handle the EditingControlShowing event
>   and then cast the editing control to a
>   TextBox and manually set the
>   UseSystemPasswordChar to true:

```
TextBox t = e.Control as TextBox;
if (t != null)
{
    t.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

in the DataGridView EditingControlShowing event

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl))
            {
                TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Control;
                txt.PasswordChar = '*';
            }
        }
```

and in the Cell Formating Event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Value != null)
                e.Value = new String('*', e.Value.ToString().Length);
        }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Why in the world would you try to do this manually when you can set the `UseSystemPasswordChar` property to "True" and let the system handle it for you automatically? The examples you've provided don't even make sense together—why bother setting the `PasswordChar` if you're going to hardcode an asterisk in the `CellFormatting` event handler method anyway?